# How to format the out put from database in shell scripting

Tags: shell, awk

I have written shell scripting and extracting records from database. And below is my result in xyz.txt file.

```
NAME
COUNT(*)
Ben 7
Tim 4
BPNAME
COUNT(*)
Mark 7
Jhon 4
```

But how do i format it as below.? So i can send email to display the same.

```
NAME   COUNT
Ben     7
Tim     4
Mark    7
Jhon    4
```

Comment: Can you give the exact contents of the file ? Because I see it has Name count and BPName count. which is confusing

Answer (score 0):

***awk*** solution:

```
awk 'BEGIN{ print "NAME","COUNT" }!/NAME|COUNT/{ print $1,$2 }' xyz.txt | column -t
```

The output:

```
NAME  COUNT
Ben   7
Tim   4
Mark  7
Jhon  4
```

Comment: Tried awk command suggested, but still same issue. My result shows like below.  NAME
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  COUNT(*)
----------
Tim
       10

Mark
        32

Matt
         7


NAME
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  COUNT(*)
----------
Martin
         5

Comment: @prashantkalloli, I suppose, I have posted improper input content

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this task with `awk`, **inclusive formatting** instead of piping to `column -t` like already suggested.

In the `BEGIN` section of `awk` you can always `print` print a header. For formatted printing you can always switch from `print` to `printf`.

After the `BEGIN` section have been executed, `printf` 1st and 2nd column only if there is no (`!`) pattern like `NAME` or (`|`) `COUNT`.

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{ printf "NAME\tCOUNT\n" } !/NAME|COUNT/ { printf "%s\t%s\n",  $1,$2 }' file
```